# Create pandas DataFrame using numpy repeat function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to create a pandas DataFrame in which one of the columns makes use of the numpy repeat function multiple times. Here's how I do this in R using `c` and `rep` and it works:

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-12-01'), as.Date('2019-12-01'), by='month'),
  value = c(rep(0.08, 7), rep(0.06, 6)),
)
```

Here's what I'm trying in pandas but it throws the error `arrays must all be same length`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-12-01', '2019-12-01', freq='MS'),
    'value': [np.repeat(0.08, 7), np.repeat(0.06, 6)]
})
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.repeat` can take an array-like thing for the `repeats` argument.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-12-01', '2019-12-01', freq='MS'),
    'value': np.repeat([.08, .06], [7, 6])
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you need ?`append`

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-12-01', '2019-12-01', freq='MS'),
    'value': np.append(np.repeat(0.08, 7), np.repeat(0.06, 6))
})
df
Out[615]: 
         date  value
0  2018-12-01   0.08
1  2019-01-01   0.08
2  2019-02-01   0.08
3  2019-03-01   0.08
4  2019-04-01   0.08
5  2019-05-01   0.08
6  2019-06-01   0.08
7  2019-07-01   0.06
8  2019-08-01   0.06
9  2019-09-01   0.06
10 2019-10-01   0.06
11 2019-11-01   0.06
12 2019-12-01   0.06
```

Also, FYI in R

```
rep(c(0.08,0.06), c(7,6))
```

Comment: fixing `r` and `pandas` in one post... nice!